# cppcheck on linux setup issue

Tags: linux, static-code-analysis, cppcheck, sles

I downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/tree/1.77, unzipped it and gave a make command which generated cppcheck binary.

Next when I run the cppcheck on a test code no error is generated.

```
sles12-box:/home/test/cppchecker_test/cppcheck-1.77 # cppcheck /home/demo_code/test_code.c 
Checking /home/demo_code/test_code.c ...
```

The source code is

```
sles12-box:/home/test/cppchecker_test/cppcheck-1.77 # vi  /home/demo_code/test_code.c
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char cobj[7] = "yahoo";
        char    *cobjPtr = cobj;
        int iobj = 4;

        printf("###########################     CPPCHECK TEST   ############################\n");
      yahoo

}
```

When I tried to compile using the other build command specified in the above mentioned page I get below error

```
sles12-box:/home/test/cppchecker_test/cppcheck-1.77 # make SRCDIR=build CFGDIR=cfg HAVE_RULES=yes CXXFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-function"

make: pcre-config: Command not found
g++ -Ilib -Iexternals/simplecpp -Iexternals/tinyxml  -DCFGDIR=\"cfg\" -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-function -std=c++0x -DHAVE_RULES -DTIXML_USE_STL   -c -o build/analyzerinfo.o build/analyzerinfo.cpp
make: pcre-config: Command not found
g++ -Ilib -Iexternals/simplecpp -Iexternals/tinyxml  -DCFGDIR=\"cfg\" -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-function -std=c++0x -DHAVE_RULES -DTIXML_USE_STL   -c -o build/astutils.o build/astutils.cpp
make: pcre-config: Command not found
g++ -Ilib -Iexternals/simplecpp -Iexternals/tinyxml  -DCFGDIR=\"cfg\" -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-function -std=c++0x -DHAVE_RULES -DTIXML_USE_STL   -c -o build/check.o build/check.cpp
make: pcre-config: Command not found
.
.
.
```

I tried building the cppcheck 1.76 version but I get different error there:

```
sles12-box:/home/test/cppchecker_test/1.76/cppcheck-1.76.1 # sudo make install
Makefile:88: Extraneous text after `else' directive
Makefile:90: Extraneous text after `else' directive
Makefile:90: *** only one `else' per conditional.  Stop.
```

How to get the cppcheck setup ready and functional?

Comment: Also see (for your pcre-config error): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66692/apache-installation-configuration-cant-find-pcre-pcre-config-for-libpcre-not

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install the binary package? https://software.opensuse.org/package/cppcheck

re 1.77: pcre-config is part of the pcre package (most likely the development package